# How to use Meteor FlowRouter.withReplaceState

Tags: meteor, flow-router, jquery-isotope

*This is a different problem from a similar question about 'reload'. This use case has to use 'withReplaceState' to handle back button reloading.*

I've found the FlowRouter documentation for FlowRouter.withReplaceState(fn), but I've been unable to find specific code examples and can't get it working.

My problem is with Isotope, a plugin that moves elements around when window is resized. User sometimes visits Isotope page, goes to another page, re-sizes window, then presses "back" button to return to Isotope page. Page has to reload to re-trigger the Isotope layout correctly for the new window size.

This is my route. How would I use FlowRouter.withReplaceState() to ensure that user who clicks back button is not seeing the cached page?

```
FlowRouter.route( '/work', {
  action: function() {
    BlazeLayout.render( 'body-static', { 
      content:  'work',
    });
  },
});
```